# I want to travel my national country with receipt of residence card

Tags: customs-and-immigration, paperwork, italy, nepali-citizens

I'm Nepali living in Italy. My *permesso di soggiorno* is being processed. I have to go to my own country and will be back after some months. Is it okay to travel with the receipt of the *permesso di soggiorno?*

Answer (score 1):

As per Timatic, the database used by airlines:

> Residents of Italy with an expired Residence Permit  are
>     permitted to re-enter Italy. They must also have a receipt
>     issued by the Italian Post Office or Police Department
>     proving that they have applied for the new residence permit
>     in less than 60 days after the expiration date. They must
>     return to Italy directly from outside the Schengen area.

If you fulfil this condition in its entirety, you can travel and be let back into Italy